# Finite Extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Could someone say exactly how many extensions of degree $n$ the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has? In Serre's "Galois Cohomology" he says it is computed precisely in a paper by Krasner, but I can't find a copy of that paper anywhere.

Comment: Not Krasner, but it looks like [this](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~kant/publications/papers/krasner.pdf) might have what you're looking for.

Comment: Krasner paper is cited in the abstract and referenced in the bibliography of the paper directed to by @Stahl

Comment: @marwalix yes I see that. Thanks very much, @Stahl!